# Stepwise debugging of Vue-CLI

Tags: vue.js

I have a Vue project created with the `Vue CLI` and I'm having problems with the `vue.config.js`. I would like to be able to set a breakpoint *within* the Vue CLI to step through and investigate exactly what's going on.

For example, I'm having issues with the `proxy` setting and I would like to be able to step through [lib/util/prepareProxy.js](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/1a0b59142aa8797810ca90705290d960a4ee6d1e/packages/%40vue/cli-service/lib/util/prepareProxy.js) when I run `npm run serve`. How would I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Running `npm run serve` will run vue-cli-service under the hood that is a separate package of Vue itself.

`vue-cli-service` is running `webpack-dev-server` under the hood which is running by Node on your terminal (and not JS engine of the browser)

for debugging in node there are several solutions but the simplest one is using `--inspect` (update: or `--inspect-brk`) mode of Node.js.

So instead of running `npm run serve` try running:

```sh
node --inspect ./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js serve
```

Which is the underlying command that is actually running but with `--inspect` flag. this should solve your problem.

Comment: Exactly the kind of debugging I was looking for, thank you for the detailed explanation. I changed `--inspect` to `--inspect-brk` and opened it up in Chromium with `about:inspect`. Works great.

Comment: I tried using both options `--inspect` or `--inspect-brk` but I'm not able to use breakpoints in VS Code: getting "unbound breakpoint" message! I launch VS Code debug using: {
     "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach by Process ID",
            "processId": "${command:PickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug on windows machines that debugger cannot be attached in some cases (see [Unable to attach a debugger while running jest tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66198433/unable-to-attach-a-debugger-while-running-jest-tests))

So I fixed it by editing directly `node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service` and adding `--inspect-brk` argument after calling "node"

```
if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  "$basedir/node" "--inspect-brk"  "$basedir/../@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
else 
  node --inspect-brk  "$basedir/../@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
fi
exit $ret
```

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced this issue myself. I found a solution that worked for me [here](https://ckhconsulting.com/vue-typescript-debuggers/)

I haven't used Vue in some time and wanted to start a new project with VUE CLI Version 5, using TypeScript. However, every time I attempted to start the debugger, I received a message saying "We couldn't find a corresponding source location, but found some other files with the same name." After making adjustments to my launch.json, the furthest I would get is a breakpoint being hit in my app.js file.

The solution involves making changes to the vue.config.js file:

```
//vue.config.js
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
const fs = require('fs');
const { SourceMapConsumer, SourceMapGenerator } = require('source-map');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  configureWebpack() {
    return {
      devtool: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? false : 'source-map',
      plugins: [{
        apply(compiler) {
          compiler.hooks.thisCompilation.tap('Initializing Compilation', (compilation) => {
            compilation.hooks.finishModules.tapPromise('All Modules Built', async (modules) => {
              for (const module of modules) {
                if (shouldSkipModule(module)) continue;

                const pathWithoutQuery = module.resource.replace(/\?.*$/, '');
                const sourceFile = fs.readFileSync(pathWithoutQuery).toString('utf-8');
                const sourceMap = extractSourceMap(module);

                sourceMap.sources = [pathWithoutQuery];
                sourceMap.sourcesContent = [sourceFile];
                sourceMap.mappings = await shiftMappings(sourceMap, sourceFile, pathWithoutQuery);
              }
            });
          });
        }
      }]
    };

    function shouldSkipModule(module) {
      const { resource = '' } = module;

      if (!resource) return true;
      if (/node_modules/.test(resource)) return true;
      if (!/\.vue/.test(resource)) return true;
      if (!/type=script/.test(resource)) return true;
      if (!/lang=ts/.test(resource)) return true;
      if (isMissingSourceMap(module)) return true;

      return false;
    }

    function isMissingSourceMap(module) {
      return !extractSourceMap(module);
    }

    function extractSourceMap(module) {
      if (!module['_source']) return null;

      return module['_source']['_sourceMap'] ||
        module['_source']['_sourceMapAsObject'] ||
        null;
    }

    async function shiftMappings(sourceMap, sourceFile, sourcePath) {
      const indexOfScriptTag = getIndexOfScriptTag(sourceFile);

      const shiftedSourceMap = await SourceMapConsumer.with(sourceMap, null, async (consumer) => {
        const generator = new SourceMapGenerator();

        consumer.eachMapping((mapping) => {
          const {
            generatedColumn,
            generatedLine,
            originalColumn,
            originalLine,

          } = mapping;
          let original = mapping.original;
          let name = mapping.name;
          let source = sourcePath;

          if (originalLine === null || originalColumn === null) {
            name = null;
            source = null;
          }
          else {
            original = {
              column: originalColumn,
              line: originalLine + indexOfScriptTag,
            };
          }

          generator.addMapping({
            generated: {
              column: generatedColumn,
              line: generatedLine,
            },
            original,
            source,
            name
          });
        });

        return generator.toJSON();
      });

      return shiftedSourceMap.mappings;
    }

    function getIndexOfScriptTag(sourceFile) {
      const lines = sourceFile.match(/.+/g);
      let indexOfScriptTag = 0;

      for (const line of lines) {
        ++indexOfScriptTag;
        if (/<script/.test(line)) break;
      }

      return indexOfScriptTag;
    }
   },


})
```

Finally, alter your launch.json, where "my-vue-project" is the name of your project

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
     {
      

      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch", //launch
      "name": "vuejs: chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:8080",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack://my-vue-project/./src/*": "${webRoot}/src/*"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The [repo](https://github.com/fearnycompknowhow/vue-typescript-debugger) looked to have a slight error.

Answer (score -3):

Easy solution 1: Just use the Vue.js devtools, i.e.  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd

Easy solution 2: Use a debugger statement

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      message: ''
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const hello = 'Hello World!'
    debugger
    this.message = hello
  }
};
</script>
```

Difficult solution:

Set or update the devtool property inside `vue.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: 'source-map'
  }
}
```

Click on the Debugging icon in the Activity Bar to bring up the Debug view, then click on the gear icon to configure a launch.json file, selecting Chrome/Firefox: Launch as the environment. Replace content of the generated launch.json with the corresponding configuration:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "vuejs: chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:8080",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
      "breakOnLoad": true,
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///./src/*": "${webRoot}/*"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "firefox",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "vuejs: firefox",
      "url": "http://localhost:8080",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
      "pathMappings": [{ "url": "webpack:///src/", "path": "${webRoot}/" }]
    }
  ]
}
```

1. Set your breakpoint within the `Vue CLI`.
2. Run `npm serve`
3. Go to the Debug view, select the ‘vuejs: chrome/firefox’ configuration, then press F5 or click the green play button.
4. Your breakpoint should now be hit as a new browser instance opens http://localhost:8080

Comment: I was looking to debug Vue CLI itself, not my Vue code, but thank you for your answer.